# How to group mysql rows with same column value into one row?

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have two tables, keywords and data.

Table keywords have 2 columns (id, keyword), table data have 3 columns (id[foreign key of keywords.id], name, value).

I am using this query:

```
SELECT k.id, d.value, d.name
FROM keywords AS k
INNER JOIN data as d ON k.id = d.id
```

it returns something like:

```
1 123 name1
1 456 name2
2 943 name1
3 542 name1
3 532 name2
3 682 name3
```

Each id can have values from 0 to 3 (maybe more in the future).

How can I retrieve all the rows with the same id in the same row?

Like

```
1 123 456
2 943
3 542 532 682
```

I want to do this because I want to be able to sort the values.

Comment: This is the kind of transformation that it'd really be better to do application-side, rather than asking MySQL to do.

Comment: I agree with Amber, though if you still want to do with SQL only, hmm.. I would google detail for "concat" and "group by" sql functions.

Comment: I want to do this because I want to be able to sort the values, so it would be great if I could get it sorted from mysql directly. Do you know how could I easly sort each column storing it in a php array?

Comment: How exactly are you wanting to store them? Ordering isn't necessarily guaranteed to be consistent on which comes first if you concatenate them together with a `GROUP BY`...

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) like this:

```
 SELECT k.id, GROUP_CONCAT(d.value)
  FROM keywords AS k
  INNER JOIN data as d ON k.id = d.id
  GROUP BY k.id
```

Also, you may need to do `ORDER BY d.name` to get exact order of values as you want. Like this:

```
 SELECT k.id, GROUP_CONCAT(d.value ORDER BY d.name separator ' ')
  FROM keywords AS k
  INNER JOIN data as d ON k.id = d.id
  GROUP BY k.id
```

Comment: Did you forget the `GROUP BY k.id`?

Comment: @Jarkam, because you haven't used `GROUP BY k.id` in this query.

Comment: Is there a way I can retrieve the values in different columns?

Comment: Like instead of comma separated values in ONE column, having different columns for each value.

Comment: You can replace comma separated value with *anything* separated value. See the new example with `SEPARATOR ' '` which will separate the values by space. If you really want to display them in a very different way, you can split the comma separated values to individual values by your server side language (Perl, PHP, etc) and display it in any way you want. In PHP, this can be done by `explode(',', $csv);`

Comment: Yes, but if I can get them in separated columns I can easly sort anything. I NEED sorting because the query result is used in a datagrid.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, but you will need to do that with your server-side language. However, this is a separate questions, try posting as a new questions, someone *may* have a method to do that.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I will hardcode it until I can find a better way to do it.

Comment: this is exactly what i'm looking for. thanks bud @shamittomar

Comment: Be carefull, GROUP_CONCAT have a max character length 1024 by default, so you may have to use `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = you_length_here;`
[mysql.com doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)