# how to create a sql query for my given criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table named `task_assignment`.
It has following 6 fields named as:

```
testId,quesId,evaluatorId,studId and marks
```

Actually this table is used to store marks for each test including each evaluators marks for each students by question id wise.

I have testId=1, quesId=Q1 and studId=S1 as a input. So, i want to get the following information in the select query.ie,`Both evaluators(E1,E2)` marks for the given input.

The sql query don't written more than one row for this...I want query output is :20,15 in a  single row.

Please guide me to get out of this issue...

[image]

Comment: I think you want to use GROUP_CONCAT ... that will put all values in a single row ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664393/how-to-group-mysql-rows-with-same-column-value-into-one-row

Comment: I'd also suggest renaming your question to reflect what you're asking.

Comment: Your query is not returning record more than 1 because you have added condition testId=1, quesId=Q1 and studId=S1. I will return marks 20 for S1 only. And S2 is having marks 15

Comment: @AvinashT.Thanks for your suggestion.. I have reuploaded my image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you won't be able to get your desired output `20, 15`, since there is only one record which satisfies your criteria `testId = 1, quesId = Q1, studId = S1`.

But to answer your question, here's my query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(marks)
    FROM task_assignment
    WHERE testId = 1
        AND quesId = 'Q1'
        AND studId = 'S1';
```

I've tried it in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c173a/1).

**EDIT 1**

If you want to parse the output of the query in your `C#` code to store them in separate variables, you can use the `Split` function:

```
string marks = "20, 15"; //Suppose that this value came from database

int mark1 = Convert.ToInt32(marks.Split(',')[0]);
int mark2 = Convert.ToInt32(marks.Split(',')[1]);
```

The code is still error-prone depending on the value of the `marks` variable, just make sure you have validated the value.

This might be unrelated to the question, but still to help you on your task, that's my answer.

Comment: +1 for SQL fiddle didn't know it and i think its a great site!

Comment: @KaeL :Could you please tell me how to parse the value returned by GROUP_CONTACT(marks)?

Comment: @Saravanan, what do you mean parsing the value returned by `GROUP_CONCAT`? Do you want to `CAST` or `CONVERT` it to another data type?

Comment: @KaeL:am using mysql with C#.So,i want to show the values returned by GROUP_CONTACT() in to two separate variable...How do i store it?

Comment: @Saravanan, added my answer above. You can upvote my answer again if you want :) Thanks mate.