# MySQL - Query with multiple tables and relationships

Tags: mysql

I am pretty new to database-ing in general. I have got a little project that I am working and I am stumped on a query I need. I am using MySQL. Here is my setup:

I have got 4 tables:

```
1: BoeingModels
B_ID | B_ModelName | B_ModelCode | B_Registrations
_____|_____________|_____________|_________________
  1  |  Boeing 737 |  BOE-737800 |      500
  2  |  Boeing 787 |  BOE-787100 |      126

2: AirbusModels
A_ID | A_ModelName | A_ModelCode | A_Registrations
_____|_____________|_____________|_________________
  1  | Airbus A330 |   AB-A330   |      418
  2  | Airbus A380 |   AB-A380   |      126

3: AircraftParts
P_ID | PartNumber | PartName
_____|____________|__________
  1  |  J-504414  | Baggage Door
  2  |  K-774821  | Lavatory Door

4: Part2Aircraft
P2A_ID | P_ID* | B_ID* | A_ID*
_______|_______|_______|_______
   1   |   2   |   2   |
   2   |   1   |   1   |
   3   |   1   |       |   1 
   4   |   2   |       |   2
```

As you can probably see, multiple parts can apply to the same aircraft and the same part can apply to multiple aircraft. The (*) denotes a Foreign Key. The problem that I am having is writing a query that will display the info I need. Here is how I'd like the data displayed, if possible:

```
PartNumber | Applicable Aircraft
_________________________________
 J-504414  | Boeing 737, Airbus A330
 K-774821  | Boeing 787, Airbus A380
```

I have tried Googling and searching through forums but I am not in tune with the lingo yet so it has been unsuccessful trying to find a situation I can understand that is similar to mine. Can you help me out with this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a way to test this right now ... but

To get all part numbers and their applicable aircraft ... simple query joining the tables (not including any formatting you want to do on the output)

select AircraftParts.PartNumber, BoeingModels.B_ModelName, AirbusModels.A_ModelName
from AircraftParts 
join Part2Aircraft
on AircraftParts.P_ID = Part2Aircraft.P_ID
join BoeingModels
on Part2Aircraft.B_ID = BoeingModels.B_ID
join AirbusModels
on Part2Aircraft.A_ID = AirbusModels.A_ID;

Comment: The query runs successfully but I get zero results from it. I have got data in there that should be pulling...

Comment: I just noticed that 4 of your values in the joining table have null values (empty values).  That will not work for the output you are looking for.  I would suggest combining BoeingModels and AirbusModels in to one table. Then you would remove the relevant parts of the select command.

Comment: That worked! Got the data I needed. Thank you! Now, another question for you: Is it possible to combine the PartNumber rows in that query and have the applicable models be separated by commas? See my example at the end of my original post.

Comment: That type of formatting is usually done more at an application layer.  However, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664393/how-to-group-mysql-rows-with-same-column-value-into-one-row