# Selecting correlating mysql column instead of row

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

This is based off a previous question that I didn't explain properly. So Ive added a more detailed explanation and more images.

I have these 2 tables:

[image]

When I type the following code I get the results below which is not a problem.

```
select customer.travelDate, customer.customer, customer.vehicle,customer.zone, prices.cost FROM customer,prices WHERE
customer.travelDate BETWEEN prices.startDate and prices.endDate 
and customer.vehicle=prices.vehicle 
and customer.zone=prices.zones;
```

[image]

The problem is that the rates table has a lot of repetition and mistakes can be made easily when inputting new data. I want to know how to setup the same table output with a smaller "Rates" table, example below.

[image]

This table has the same values but is considerably smaller and easier to read. I know its possible to do it with php using  by only having numbers in the "Zone" row and concatenation.

```
$zoneNo = $row["zone"];
$query='Select ... FROM ... WHERE customer.zones=rates.zone'.$zoneNo;
```

but is there a way to do it within MySQL

Comment: This transformation is called pivoting. The answers to the duplicate question show you how to accomplish this transformation in mysql. However, please note, the sql-based solution is not particularly efficient, especially if the number of derived columns is dynamic. Consider using php code to transform your standard tabular database output to the required structure.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664393/how-to-group-mysql-rows-with-same-column-value-into-one-row